# In XQuery how can I list files that contain 1 or more child elements in a second list?

Tags: xquery

Using the book example seen everywhere, if I had many documents each containing a list of books, how could I list just the documents which contained one or more ISBN numbers stored in a variable?

i.e.

```
<Doc id="1">
  <ISBN code="734554656570317" 
  <ISBN code="234363495740647" 
  <ISBN code="833563495780345" 

<Doc id="2">
  <ISBN code="467467546756747" 
  <ISBN code="890473590555875" 
  <ISBN code="234557857667412"
```

etc

How can I achieve something like:

declare variable $isbnList := ("833563495780345", "234557857667412");

for $doc in /Doc
where $doc/ISBN[@code in $isbnList]

Comment: If you know the number of node set you want to path to you might want to use the "or" operator.

Answer (score 2):

If $isbnList contains a sequence of atomic items, each of which is a string ISBN code, this should work:

```
/Doc[ISBN/@code = $isbnList]
```

( = performs a general comparison and will return true if at least one item on the left matches at least one item on the right, for example (1, 2) = (2, 3) returns true).